# Multiple column header: splitting column header into two

Tags: wpf

I need to show some data in a listview. I am using wpf with visual studio 2008.
I need to show 'type' and its 'value' in listviews gridview column. But the 'value' columnheader is splitted into two. it should show[image] min and max values.
 Can anyone help me to achieve this?